# Mesh with editing failures

Tags: mesh, mirror

I'm new to blender and I was interested in using it to develop game mods.
I started with a simple one and am having problems with the mesh of the personage's legs.

I edited the right side of the leg and then used Modifiers> mirror to mirror the other leg. But the other leg appeared with cuts in the mesh.
I used the remove double and the mesh has dark spots. How can I solve this?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try resetting the normals for the faces, in *Edit Mode*, select all the faces, go to *Mesh* at the top selection bar or press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>, then set *Normals from Face*.

Comment: Thank you very much. Fixed it. I was having this problem a lot with all the mesh.

Comment: No problem, nice model by the way.